# Problem after upgrade to 3.6.1

Tags: javascript

Really wishing there was a role-back feature installed. I upgraded last night, now when I open the dashboard one of the javascript modules is causing an infinite loop by including the 'Welcome to Wordpress' screen into the 'Wordpress Blog' widget. Is there an easy way to role-back without data loss?

Update:
The problem stems from one of the plugins. None of the deactivate links worked so renamed each directory then re-enabled them one by one. The problem has gone but I can't risk this happening again on the live site. Currently I don't know which plugin caused the problem, but I have an inkling. What could cause the problem I experienced and what should I be looking for in the source?

Also, Can't find a relevant tag for this question.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by "infinite loop by including"? 3.6.1 was minor security update, unlikely to cause issues by itself so something might have gone wrong with update process in general.

Comment: @Rarst What I mean is, the Blog widget's content is the welcome screen which includes the Blog widgets whose contents are... It's probably a plugin, trying to narrow down the issue now.

Comment: You should enable [debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), if you wish to see what's going on when there is an issue. If the issue is gone and if it can't be reproduced, then there is no way to guess what would have gone wrong with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a backup of your site before any change, including the updates of the WP core, so you can restore if anything goes wrong. That is a gold rule that every webmaster should know. It is possible that you have learnt this lesson just now. Also, it is a good practice to have a copy of your site with the same config and same set of plugins where you can test any change, including the update of the WP core, before make them in the real site.

You can download the WP 3.6 version [here](http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/) and copy over the current files. But you must know that the 3.6.1 version include some security issues fixed, so it is currently the more secured version and you should find what is causing your problem and update as soon as possible.

The most probable is that the problem was caused by a plugin. I recomend you to deactivate all the plugins, test that all is ok and then activate one by one to find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: This is my testing ground that has gone wrong. The live site has not yet been updated. Just copied the 3.6.1 files over the original but problem persists.

Comment: You asked about a way to have again the 3.6 version without data loss and I give you an answer about how to do it. If you want to ask about what is going wrong in your site you should edit your question or, better, make a new one because it is really different of your original question.